# What's happening with the Ender's Game movie?

Tags: movie, enders-game

*** UPDATE: Movie is out in theaters as of 2013 ***

---

I'm not asking for rumor here, but verifiable fact.  Anyone know what the status of the Ender's Game movie is?  Last I heard it was in something of development hell.  But Wikipedia suggests that things have gotten moving again since then.  Anyone know anything?  Maybe someone with access to IMDB pro?

Comment: Still going to be rumour and speculation if the source isn't one of the crew themselves

Comment: @Eight Days Not necessarily.  There are reputable sources for this sort of information that are not simply rumor, even if they are not first degree sources.

Comment: I'm torn.  I would love to see a movie about Ender's Game, but how bad could they screw it up.  Need I say "Starship Troopers"?

Comment: You could ask at http://hatrack.com/contact.shtml (i.e. get an answer straight from the horse's mouth).

Comment: @Tony I've been a poster on the Hatrack River Forums a long time.  They're pretty bored with this question over there ;)

Comment: @Daniel I see you're from Bloomington, IN. IU grad per chance? I'm a Purdue guy so we might have to do battle

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: @daniel I didn't mean ask on the forums, I mean officially ask.  If you can't get an official answer there, then ISTM that means that you can only get rumour anywhere.

Comment: Please see [How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates) on why questions like this are bad for SciFi.SE.

Comment: According to one reviewer, the first successful adaptation of Ender's Game was released in August under the name [Rise of the Planet of the Apes](http://greensboro.rhinotimes.com/Articles-c-2011-08-10-209178.112113-Ape-Rise-And-Guest-Judges.html)

Answer (score 15):

According to [Time.com](http://techland.time.com/2010/09/21/enders-game-movie-back-on/), the project is still ongoing, citing that Gavin Hood has taken up re-writing of the script as well as the project's director. He previously worked on *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

[Summit Entertainment is acquiring the rights to development](http://www.deadline.com/2011/04/franchise-hungry-summit-plays-enders-game-with-filmmaker-gavin-hood/) and is co-financing the film.  The current producers are Orson Scott Card himself, Roberto Orci, Alex Kurtzman, Gigi Pritzker, Linda McDonough, and Lynn Hendee.

The current plan is to put the film into production by early 2012.

Answer (score 7):

Update: The movie [put out casting calls last month](http://io9.com/5844789/the-enders-game-movie-puts-out-casting-calls-for-10-characters--including-ender) for several of the main characters:

> The casting calls appear to be from a draft of the script, written by Star Trek's Roberto Orci and Alex Kurtzman, and they give a pretty good idea of just how closely this film will stick to the book's story.

Here's a description of the movie Ender:

> He's depicted as smart and sensitive, but also incredibly ruthless. And he's ten years old — older than in the book, but not as old as Hollywood was trying to make him at one point. There are a few scenes where he worries about being like his cut-throat brother Peter, and confides in his sister Valentine. Just like in the book, he dishes out a rough treatment to Bonzo Madrid, his former platoon leader, when Bonzo tries to bully him too much. And then he feels bad about it. The screenplay also includes some scenes where Ender has weird nightmares about the buggers — and he tries to understand where the buggers are coming from, and what their children are like. Ender is pissed at Graff because he keeps changing the rules in the war "exercises."
>   !The scene where Ender finds out that his final victory was not, in fact, a game is pretty intense, and features Ender and Graff both trying to talk at the same time. Ender is saying "They came to establish a colony, we chased them away... in fifty years they have never returned," while Graff is saying, "It makes no difference now," and then Ender is saying "Now I am become death, the destroyer of worlds," at the same time as Graff is saying "What are you talking about?" Finally, Ender is saying "I will bear the shame of this xenocide forever," at the same moment as Graff is saying, "You will be remembered as a hero." It ends with Ender getting an injection, knocking him out.